# Checkmark pushes cell content in UITableVIewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

I'm building a filter view controller. 
The top section is a selectable list that the selection is being marked with checkmark.

My problem is that the checkmark pushes my textlabel to the left. 
The UITextLabel is aligned right to left.

[image]

How do i disable the checkmark from pushing the textlabel so it would work like the ringtone selection viewController in iphone (for example)

[image]

Comment: Do you have a custom cell or how do you add the checkmark?

Comment: Yes a custom Cell with a label in it.
at didSelectAtRow I wrote .  cell?.accessoryType = .checkmark

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle manually the checkmark adding an `UIImage` at the left of the `UITableViewCell` and not using `accessoryType` because it appears only at the right: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623228-accessorytype

But if you want to still use `accessoryType` you can give more space at the right of the `UILabel`.